# Python Reading XML Child

Tags: python, xml

Trying to parse this XML but I can't seem to figure out quite where I'm going wrong.

Snippet of XML:

```
<thexml timestamp="2017-01-02T10:17:41">
<event="41" date="2017-04-01" id="5543" time="09:30:00" type="seat" link="na"></event>
</thexml>
```

I'm trying:

```
DOMTree = parseString(response.content)
collection = DOMTree.documentElement
selections = collection.getElementsByTagName("event")
for select in selections:
 print "event found"
```

This seems to work it triggers on the events in the XML. Trying to get the type, for example, is stumping me with this format.

```
tags = select.getElementsByTagName("type")
```

When I use this the string for tags becomes  which suggests it found it. But I'm not sure how to actually read the string of the child. I've been trying variations on:

```
print type.childNodes[0].data
print type.childNodes.data
print type.data
```

Am I missing something really obvious here? I parse a bunch of XML's but this format is throwing me a bit. Would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: The XML you provided is not valid. `ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token):` Are you sure this is the exact XML you try to parse?

Comment: Fixed a typo in the XML snippet sorry. I'm using xml.dom.minidom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still had a problem in your xml.

Here is the fix (and how to extract the relevant attributes):

```
In [17]: c = """<thexml timestamp="2017-01-02T10:17:41">
    ...: <event date="2017-04-01" id="5543" time="09:30:00" type="seat" link="na"></event>
    ...: </thexml>
    ...: """
In [18]: DOMTree = parseString(c)
In [19]: collection = DOMTree.documentElement
In [20]: s = collection.getElementsByTagName('event')
In [21]: for e in s:
    ...:     print(e.getAttribute('type'))
    ...:
seat
```

> Note that in your example - `type` is an `Attribute` (And not `Node`) so you can't use `getElementsByTagName("type")`, you will need to use `getAttribute`

Comment: Oh jeez I'm an idiot. Thanks for that much appreciated.